# Get Total Orders placed in the particular category when querying Order details

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a orders table that have order detail and the column named Category where Category is the type of order.

Now the customer can search the order details.

Now what i want to write a query the show the order details and a column called TotalOrder that will show the TotalOrders placed by all customers for that category,

Example Say the Order Table like

```
OrderID  CustomerID  OrderDetails Category   
1         1           test         A1
2         1           test1        A2
3         2           test3        A2
4         3           test4        A2
```

So if query for the order id 1

It will result like with Order ID 2

```
OrderID   Cust_ID     OrderDetails  Category      TotalOrdersInThisCategory
2         1           test          A2            3
```

This scenario is a demonstration of the actual problem.

How can i achieve this?

Do i need to fetch the Order detail in one query and Another query with group by Category clause and then make a inner join. Any better ideas is appreciable.

The order details will have few millions of records.

**Please Suggest Some Better Title of this question**

Any help is appreciated

Comment: I don't understand your example, you said `OrderId` 2, but put the details of `OrderdId` 1, and 3 totals on the category `A1` that should be just 1...

Comment: @Lamak Really sorry, mistakenly write A1 instead of A2. I have solve this by violating Dry principle, as i first create a CTE with Group by Category and then make an inner join with the query, can you please provide some better example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  OrderID,
  Cust_ID,
  OrderDetails,
  Category,
  (select count(*) from orders where category = o.category) TotalOrdersInThisCategory  
FROM
  Orders o
```

or you could try this:

```
SELECT 
  o.OrderID,
  o.Cust_ID,
  o.OrderDetails,
  o.Category,
  c.TotalOrdersInThisCategory  
FROM
  Orders o
INNER JOIN (select category, count(*) from orders group by category) c
        ON o.Category = c.Category
```

Comment: My orders table have tens of millions of records so if i try to search some hundred orders it will have a very big performance hit with this code. So this might not be useful for production purpose. Or what you think??

Comment: Best way to tell is to profile a couple of approaches, and see which one your platform likes best. I've added another way of doing it to my original answer..

Comment: Actually the second method is better than the first but i am doing in the same way   just using CTE in place of (select category, count(*) from orders group by category) c. But there is no difference in the speed, But thanks for the post

Answer (score 2):

You can try this and see if it runs better:

```
SELECT *
FROM (  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Category) TotalOrdersInThisCategory
        FROM OrderTable) A
WHERE OrderId = 2
```

Comment: no, the  SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Category) TotalOrdersInThisCategory
        FROM OrderTable is itself taking too much time as The OrderTable have huge amount of data.